# Using the email as primary key in Cassandra, best practices?

Tags: cassandra

We're developing a web application and we would like to use the email as primary key so we can use lightweight transactions to avoid people registering with he same email. But then we have the problem of generating URLs for the user profile. We cannot use the email in the URL.

We have been thinking about hashing he email (with bcrypt, for example) and use this as the primary key, then the URLs won't expose he email. Is this a good practice?

Other solutions involve using more than one table for the user information, but that makes the process of avoiding email duplicates more complex.

Any suggestion?

**EDIT:** After giving it some though, maybe there is a solution. Using stardard UUID for the primary key, and then use a second table email_to_uuid with primary key on the email column. When a new user registers, we generate an UUID and perform a lightweight transaction inserting a new value in the email_to_uuid able (IF NOT EXSIST). After that, we read the table using the email and if the UUID is the one we have just generated, then we got a correct user registration and can proceed to insert the data in the main table. Does this approach sound correct?

Comment: Your edit demonstrates a workable solution and a pretty good pattern to use, as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is a though one in Cassandra: there are two ways of doing this. Either you use the eMail as `Primary Key` and encode it in the URI, e.g. using BASE64. This way the eMail is immutable and can only be deleted and re-inserted to change it.

The other way is using an artificial Primary Key, like your BCrypt, a hash, `TIMEUUID`, or `UUID`, and put an `Index` or `Clustering Column` onto the eMail column.

Your way you choose will determine how flexible and performant your application is. If you can relax flexibility or wish less data in this table you may go with the first way and encode the URI; if the changing of the eMail is important you may consider taking an artificial `Primary Key`. Either of the solutions have their benefits: it is totally up to you what you like best.

Comment: I think that the second option is not really a good one since using an index on emails (high cardinality) is an [anti-patern](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html).

Comment: You are totally right. It is better using it as partition key or some identifier instead. And as clustering columns are similar to Indices it may be best having eMail or any unique identifier when querying for your account. Thanks for your comment: this is important to keep in mind.